# Installed cheap foreign door locks. Now door is stuck closed

Tags: locks, door, solenoid

2008 Yukon XL. I usually know better but the allure of an $80/4 pack of door lock solenoids vs. $180/each was too good not to at least try. Of course I didn't count on Murphy's Law.

I managed to replace the driver's side solenoid before it failed to open the door completely, instead of just intermittently. The front passenger door was not so fortunate. Pulling the inside or outside door handle does nothing.

I'm looking for a way to get the door open without a large amount of damage to the outside of the door or the inside panel. My current working theory is drilling a small hole through the inside panel, and running something like a wire hanger to the solenoid in an attempt to reset the latch so it can open with a handle.

### Update

The interior door panel cannot be removed with the door closed. I am unsure if a slim jim would help since the cable from the inside handle is connected fine, but I can explain more about what's going on with the solenoid in more detail.

Here's some pics of the solenoid:

Stock pic

[image]

These show how the cable routes from the inside handle through so the metal connector lifts up when the handle is pulled and releases the latch:

[image]

[image]

What happens is, when the door is locked, and someone attempts to pull the handle to unlock it, the metal connector lifts up and the door correctly doesn't open, but the lip does not reset to it's normal position. So, when the door is unlocked, pulling the handle does nothing because the lip is in the wrong position.

I've had success with repeated un/locking with the key fob and "gently" tapping the outside of the door with a cloth-covered rubber mallet, but lately that hasn't yielded any success.

Comment: Can you employ something like a "slim jim" or your coathanger through the rubber seal at the bottom of the window glass? You've been inside there, perhaps you recall where the important parts are.

Comment: The solenoid shouldn't prevent you from being able to open the door from the inside, did you replace the entire mechanism?

Comment: Can you not remove the interior door panel will the door closed?

Comment: Before cutting into a panel, I would try identifying the wires that run to the door lock, disconnect them, then putting power onto them to see if that will make the lock operate.

Comment: @HandyHowie unfortunately the power is confirmed working, the issue is mechanical in nature.

Comment: Yes, but the BCM may only be applying power for a brief moment.  If you apply the power manually, you will be able to keep the power on longer while you manoeuvre (bang on) the door etc.

Comment: Can you disconnect the battery and open one door with the key?

Comment: @WeatherVane - A key may unlock, but it won't open the door.

Comment: I have seen cars in UK where (when the battery is flat) you can slide a physical key out of the fob to open the door mechanically.